# How to implement search in listview properly?

Tags: c#, linq, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an `EditText`, implemented linq to filter/search in listview but my problem is whenever I type the item name it shows the filtered item but when I delete the text, the listview doesn't refresh. Any workaround for this?

my code

```
void mSearch_TextChanged(object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e)
 {           
        List<Mountain> searchedMountains = (from mountain in mMountains
                                            where mountain.MtName.Contains(mSearch.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                                            select mountain).ToList();

            mAdapter.Update(searchedMountains);          
            RunOnUiThread(() => mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged());    
 }
```

My Update method in my adapter:

```
public  void Update(List<Mountain> mLists)
{
        mtList.Clear();
        mtList.AddRange(mLists);
        NotifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

thinking about creating a new method in my adapter.. hmm..

Comment: have you tried using e.Text instead of mSearch.Text?

Comment: I think the problem is that the TextChanged event does not fire while you erasing the text, put a break point there and try to debug it.

Comment: have tried yet jason.. i will try your suggestions

Comment: @Jason how can I do that? getting an error when changing the mSearch.Text to e.Text

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: @Jason there are no errors, seems that the app is crashing and not responding when I put breakpoint

Comment: hello sir I've tried reinstantiating the adapter then notifysetdatachanged.. It worked fine but it doesnt get the right data in my detail activity.. please help me.. this is the only missing piece in my application and our team is ready to go on our defense.. please lend a hand :(